# Is it possible to reuse 3DS nintendo account on a Switch? Is there any benefit in doing so?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-network-id, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I already have a Nintendo account created on a 3DS. When adding a new user on a Switch, I have a choice between logging into an existing account or creating a new one.

Will I be able to use the account I have created on a 3DS with a Switch? If yes, what will be carried over from 3DS to the Switch? Or is it just that I will have the same username and password on both systems, but apart from that the accounts will be separate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [Nintendo Support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16015/%7E/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nintendo-account-and-nintendo-network-id%3F) article, you cannot directly use the account you set up with your 3DS. A 3DS system uses an account that is tied to a Nintendo Network ID, which functions differently than accounts tied to a Switch.

> Nintendo Accounts and Nintendo Network IDs are used for different purposes.
>
> **Nintendo Account**
>
> - A Nintendo Account is used for Nintendo Switch online services (including the Nintendo Switch eShop), smart device applications (like Super Mario Run), off-device software purchases, and the My Nintendo loyalty service.
>
> **Nintendo Network ID**
>
> - A Nintendo Network ID (NNID) is created and used on a Wii U and/or Nintendo 3DS family system.
> - NNIDs are used for online features (such as online multiplayer or interactions) and for purchasing downloadable software through Nintendo eShop on Wii U and Nintendo 3DS

You can link your 3DS account to your Switch account, which [this article](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15990) provides information on how to do that. The benefit for linking your accounts provides the ability to share funds between your systems.

> Additionally, a Nintendo Network ID can be linked to a Nintendo Account to share Nintendo eShop funds across the different systems.

Comment: In addition to shared balance, it also will also suggestion friends you had on the 3DS if they have a linked Nintendo Account.